# Android Wear Add Library from Existing app

Tags: android, module, wear-os

I have an existing app that I'm trying to build an Android Wear module out of. I need to access the codes/module of that existing app.

I understand that to add a library normally, I do `compile project(':app')` in `build.gradle`.

And I have to change this `apply plugin: 'com.android.application'` to  `apply plugin: 'com.android.library'` as well as take out the applicationId of the library/module being added.

When I change the aforementioned for the existing app to accommodate my Android Wear module, it wrecks the existing app.

How do I add the module/codes of an existing app to my Android library?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're correct that one app can't reference the code of another *app*; the referenced code needs to be in a library module (which is not itself an app).

What you probably want to do is create a library module separate from your original app, and set both apps (Wear and original) up to reference it, as you already described. Then you start the process of moving code that you want available to both from your original app into the library module. This unfortunately tends to be fairly laborious, teasing the common bits out in a way that doesn't break your original app - and you'll undoubtedly find more dependencies than you'd really like.

Yes, it's kind of a pain, but AFAIK there's no better way.

Comment: If this answered your question, it's customary to accept the answer. :^)